# Multiple conditions for same table in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting products using given parameters (name of real entity and columns changed for illustration purposes),

```
    public IQueryable<Product> GetProductsByPara(string price, string weight, string dimensions, string trend)
    {
        var result = dbContext.Products.Where(a =>
            a.Price.ToLower().Equals(price.ToLower()) && 
            a.Weight.ToLower().Equals(weight.ToLower()) &&
            a.Dimensions.ToLower().Equals(dimensions.ToLower()) &&
            a.Trend.ToLower().Equals(trend.ToLower()));
        if (result.Any())
        {
            return result;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(price))
        {
            result = dbContext.Products.Where(a =>
                a.Price.ToLower().Equals(price.ToLower()) && 
                a.Weight.ToLower().Equals(weight.ToLower()) &&
                a.Trend.ToLower().Equals(trend.ToLower()));
            if (result.Any())
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dimensions))
        {
            result = dbContext.Products.Where(a =>
                a.Dimensions.ToLower().Equals(dimensions.ToLower()) &&
                a.Weight.ToLower().Equals(weight.ToLower()) &&
                a.Trend.ToLower().Equals(trend.ToLower()));
            if (result.Any())
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why are price and weight `strings`? That makes no sense.

Comment: @BCdotWEB As mentioned in question, names are changed for illustration purposes. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach to get rid of some of the redundancy:

First write an extension Method

```
static IQueryable<Product> FilterForParameters
    (this IQueryable<Product> query, string price, string weight, string dimensions, string trend)
{
    if (price != null)
        query = query.Where(p => p.Price.ToLower().Equals(price.ToLower()));

    if (weight != null)
        query = query.Where(p => p.Weight.ToLower().Equals(weight.ToLower()));

    if (dimensions != null)
        query = query.Where(p => p.Dimension.ToLower().Equals(dimensions.ToLower()));

    if (trend != null)
        query = query.Where(p => p.Trend.ToLower().Equals(trend.ToLower()));

    return query;
}
```

Then change your method

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProductsByPara(string price, string weight, string dimensions, string trend)
{
    var products = dbContext.Products;

    var productsFilterdByAll = products.FilterForParameters(price, weight, dimensions, trend);
    if (productsFilterdByAll.Any())
        return productsFilterdByAll;

    var productsFilterdByAllButDimnensions = products.FilterForParameters(price, weight, null, trend);
    if (productsFilterdByAllButDimnensions.Any())
        return productsFilterdByAllButDimnensions;

    var productsFilterdByAllButPrice = products.FilterForParameters(null, weight, dimensions, trend);
    return productsFilterdByAllButPrice;
}
```

Depending on the context, it would also be a good idea to check your parameters for null at the beginning of the method.

Answer (score 0):

use `ternary operator` as `condition ? true : false;`

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProductsByPara(string price, string weight, string dimensions, string trend)
{
    return dbContext.Products.Where(a =>
                   a.Price.Equals(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dimensions) ? a.Price : price,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                && a.Weight.Equals(weight, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                && a.Dimensions.Equals(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(price) ? a.Dimensions : dimensions, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                && a.Trend.Equals(trend, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
            );
}
```

It is unnecessary to repeat:

```
if (result.Any())
{
    return result;
}
```

.

Also, using `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` would be much more appropriate than   `ToLower()`

Comment: OP is changing the content of `result`. So checking for `result.Any()` multiple times is actually a reasonable thing to do.